# pip install via a vba macro

Tags: vba, pip

I have created a .bat file to download Selenium. But I want to run it through a VBA macro. Can I incorporate below code in a vba script. I don't want to run a separate batch command.

```
@ECHO ON
IF EXIST C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3_64 (
    set root=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3_64
) ELSE IF EXIST C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64 (
    set root=C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64
) ELSE (
    set root=C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64
)
cd %root%
IF EXIST %root%\envs\jup369 (
    call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%\envs\jup369
) ELSE (
    call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%
)
pip install selenium
```

Comment: I have removed your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, _(and other invalid tags)_, because they're irrelevant to your question task. You do not want a batch file, and therefore it has no purpose even being posted. I have therefore changed your title and tags, so that you are not directing your question to the wrong audiences, and receiving more answers you did not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this code line:

```
Shell "pathToTheBatFile\test.bat", vbNormalFocus
```

Or create and run bat file in a hidden window:

```
Sub createRunBatFile()
   Dim strCode As String, batName As String
   strCode = "@ECHO ON" & vbCrLf & _
            "IF EXIST C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3_64 (" & vbCrLf & _
            "set root=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3_64" & vbCrLf & _
            ") ELSE IF EXIST C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64 (" & vbCrLf & _
            "set root=C:\Programs\Miniconda3_64" & vbCrLf & _
            ") ELSE (" & vbCrLf & _
            "set root=C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64" & vbCrLf & _
            ")" & vbCrLf & _
            "cd %root%" & vbCrLf & _
            "IF EXIST %root%\envs\jup369 (" & vbCrLf & _
            "call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%\envs\jup369" & vbCrLf & _
            ") ELSE (" & vbCrLf & _
            "call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%" & vbCrLf & _
            ")" & vbCrLf & _
            "pip install selenium"
            
   batName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.bat"
   Open batName For Output As 1#
        Print #1, strCode
   Close 1#
   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Selenium is going to be installed...", 1, "Installation Confirmation", 0
   Shell batName, 0
   MsgBox "Selenium installed.", vbInformation, "Installation done"
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to write above code in vba. I dont want to create a separate .bat file .

Comment: can we hide cmd window and add a message after completion

Comment: Try changing of `vbNormalFocus` with `vbHide` (or 0). I can show you how to create such a bat file in vba and run it after. I think it can be done in VBA, but more complicated...

Comment: how can I add a message here. Like "Installing" during installation and "Installation Done" post installation.

Comment: @Mohit If you add such a message before running the bat file, nothing will run until you press OK. I can use a VBScript message, able to close itself in a second, if this is what you wont...

Comment: thanks.. and can I use batName = %temp% & "\test.bat" to create .bat file in temp folder.

Comment: @Mohit Not exactly... You may try `Environ("TEMP") & "\test.bat"`. I adapted the code to send the two messages.